# mongo query to combine data from two document

Tags: mongodb

i have two document one is userRole(Role Master) and another is user(Role Asssociated with user),user can have multiple role and there is some permissions applied on user level and role level both , i want to fetch distinct permission from user and userRole for particular user and on associate multiple role on this user..??

```js
"userRole":{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58902f6b5d474004b4034026"),
    "roleName" : "Filler",
    "permission" : {
        "ActionPermissions" : {
            "Incidence Management" : {
                "Trouble Ticketing" : {
                    "Add Ticket" : {}
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "associatePermission" : {
        "ActionPermissions" : {
            "Incidence Management" : {
                "Trouble Ticketing" : {
                    "Add Ticket" : {},
                    "Bulk Closure" : true
                },
                "Ageing Report" : {
                    "Filter Report" : true
                }
            },
            "Preventive Maintenance" : {
                "Edit Ticket" : {
                    "Severity" : true
                }
            }
        },
        "DataPermissions" : {
            "Incidence Management" : {
                "Trouble Ticketing" : {
                    "Add Ticket" : {}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```js
"user": {
    "_id" : ObjectId("58a29743f7d4180a4cae827e"),
    "firstName" : "dileep",
    "roles" : [ 
        {
            "roleName" : {
                "_id" : "5890336b5d474004b403402c",
                "roleName" : "Ceo"
            },
            "effectiveFrom" : "2017-02-16T18:30:00.000Z",
            "effectiveTo" : "2017-02-28T18:30:00.000Z",
            "id" : {}
        }, 
        {
            "effectiveFrom" : "2017-02-16T18:30:00.000Z",
            "effectiveTo" : ISODate("2017-02-15T18:30:00.000Z"),
            "roleName" : "{\"_id\":\"5890335d5d474004b4034029\",\"roleName\":\"Engineer\"}"
        }, 
        {
            "roleName" : {
                "_id" : "5890336b5d474004b403402c",
                "roleName" : "Ceo"
            },
            "effectiveFrom" : "2017-02-16T18:30:00.000Z",
            "effectiveTo" : ISODate("2017-02-28T18:30:00.000Z"),
            "id" : {}
        }, 
        {
            "roleName" : {
                "_id" : "589033795d474004b403402f",
                "roleName" : "WebUser"
            },
            "id" : {}
        }, 
        {
            "roleName" : {
                "_id" : "58a69b9a93e8e20854282001",
                "roleName" : "surbhi",
                "roleDescription" : "surbhi"
            },
            "effectiveFrom" : "2017-02-23T18:30:00.000Z",
            "id" : 5
        }, 
        {
            "roleName" : {
                "_id" : "58aef573d90ffd185c96bb65",
                "roleName" : "ty",
                "roleDescription" : ""
            },
            "effectiveFrom" : "2017-02-23T18:30:00.000Z",
            "id" : 6
        }
    ],
    "groups" : [ 
        {
            "groupName" : {
                "_id" : "5891d9e75d4740205401bd68",
                "groupName" : "Power Vendor"
            },
            "effectiveFrom" : "2017-02-17T18:30:00.000Z",
            "id" : 1,
            "effectiveTo" : ISODate("2017-02-15T18:30:00.000Z")
        }, 
        {
            "groupName" : {
                "_id" : "5891d9f15d4740205401bd6b",
                "groupName" : "Tower Co"
            },
            "effectiveFrom" : "2017-02-21T18:30:00.000Z",
            "effectiveTo" : ISODate("2017-02-28T18:30:00.000Z"),
            "id" : 2
        }, 
        {
            "groupName" : {
                "_id" : "5891d9f15d4740205401bd6b",
                "groupName" : "Tower Co"
            },
            "effectiveFrom" : "2017-02-21T18:30:00.000Z",
            "effectiveTo" : ISODate("2017-02-21T18:30:00.000Z"),
            "id" : 2
        }, 
        {
            "groupName" : {
                "_id" : "58a6bfa3ea436926ac06a234",
                "groupName" : "asdasd",
                "groupDescription" : "asd"
            },
            "effectiveFrom" : "2017-02-27T18:30:00.000Z",
            "id" : 4
        }, 
        {
            "groupName" : {
                "_id" : "58a6958e93e8e20854282000",
                "groupName" : "anas",
                "groupDescription" : "this group is made for testing purpose."
            },
            "effectiveFrom" : "2017-02-20T18:30:00.000Z",
            "id" : 5,
            "effectiveTo" : ISODate("2017-02-21T18:30:00.000Z")
        }, 
        {
            "groupName" : {
                "_id" : "58a69dbb93e8e20854282002",
                "groupName" : "GP",
                "groupDescription" : "gp is for test"
            },
            "effectiveFrom" : "2017-02-23T18:30:00.000Z",
            "effectiveTo" : "2017-03-01T18:30:00.000Z",
            "id" : 6
        }, 
        {
            "effectiveFrom" : ISODate("2017-02-26T18:30:00.000Z"),
            "groupName" : {
                "groupName" : "Tower CoMPANY",
                "_id" : "5891d9f15d4740205401bd6b"
            },
            "effectiveTo" : null,
            "id" : 7
        }
    ],
    "profilePic" : "UserProfilePic-1487050584447.jpg",
    "loginId" : "dileep123",
    "password" : null,
    "confirmPassword" : null,
    "imeiNumber1" : "222222222222222222",
    "middleName" : "kumara",
    "lastName" : "saxenaaaaaa",
    "primaryEmail" : "ok@gmail.com",
    "primaryPhoneNumber" : "1111111111",
    "associatePermission" : {
        "ActionPermissions" : {
            "Incidence Management" : {},
            "User Management" : {
                "Users" : {
                    "View" : true,
                    "Add" : true
                }
            }
        },
        "DataPermissions" : {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `$lookup`,
https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup

Here is a [good example](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-joins-in-mongodb-nosql-databases/) that resonates how to go about it

Comment: i tried using above shared links but not able to found desired output actually i want distinct associate permission from both the collection basis on RoleID join..e.g. in user collection if user have 2 permission and user is associate with 3 roles then all roles permission should be come with this document..

Comment: select permission from role where roleID in (SELECT roleID from user where userID = 123)  Union Select permission from user where userID = 123;                                                                                                                   i want to write above query in mongoDB